# What is the best way to join 'and' and 'or' together?

Tags: conjunctions, writing-style

What is the best way to join 'or' and 'and' together? 'or/and' or 'and/or'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Become a logician and say *or*. :^)

I also vote for *and/or* but dislike it stylistically. So here are some alternatives.

> You can have cake and/or death. --> You can have cake or death or both. -OR- You can have cake, death, or both.
>
> You can have cake, death, whippings, and/or nuts. --> You can have any or all of cake, death, whippings, or nuts. -OR- You can have any combination of....
>
> You must have cake and/or death. --> You can't have neither cake nor death.

Maybe the last one is a stretch for non-technically-minded audiences. Maybe.

Comment: I don't want neither cake nor death.

Answer (score 2):

I've only seen it as "and/or" and "and or" without the slash. I have not seen it in the form "or/and" before!

EDIT: I would actually try and avoid it if possible by rewriting!

Comment: RE avoiding it: "Or" is normally understood to include the "and" case when the options are not clearly mutually exclusive. Peronally I save "and/or" for cases where there is serioius danger of ambiguity. Otherwise your text gets littered with this awkward construct.

Comment: Strunk and White's *And/or* entry in their book *The Elements of Style*: "A device, or shortcut, that damages a sentence and often leads to confusion or ambiguity."